# IIS does not redirect to external domain (web.config)

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I wrote a rule to redirect all files to be served from a new domain :

```
<rule name="Redirect files" stopProcessing="false">
   <match url="^/?subdirectory/files(/.*)?$" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://newDomain{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

What I'm expecting for a URL like :

*https://oldDomain/subdirectory/files/file.png*

To be redirected to

*https://newDomain/file.png*

But what I get is :

*https://oldDomain/file.png*

No matter what I try, it's always under the oldDomain, I tried to move this rule to the end of the rules list, but it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your rule and it looks 100% correct. Most probably your browser cached 301 redirect. All that you need to do is clear your cache in browser

Comment: thank you for your time and your help, actually I always use `Ctrl + F5` so cache is cleared, did you test it in an server where the protocol is **HTTPS** or **HTTP** ? Because this work on my developement environement where I only have **HTTP**

Comment: Please, try in incognito then, because i am not sure that `Ctrl + F5` will clear  redirects cache

Comment: I used another browser and clear all cache, still getting the same result, I don't know but I have a strange feeling that it has something to do with the HTTPS or the server configuration, I mean why the server does always append the oldDomain to my redirect, it's like it's not allowed to redirect to an external domain or something

Comment: Can you try to move this rule as first one and set  `stopProcessing="true"`

Comment: it's the first rule, and I'm not using `stopProcessing="true"` because I have other rules for clean URL and things like this that should be processed too, but I'll give it a try

Comment: I changed the value to `true` and cleared the browser cache, still the same result, I don't know I may ask for HTTPS to be removed just for test, if it's the source of the problem, or another IIS configuration.